# regexp error when filtering command output

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, ash

I want to filter the lines from the following command:

```
$ cat /proc/net/route
Iface   Destination     Gateway         Flags   RefCnt  Use     Metric  Mask            MTU     Window  IRTT                               
br-lan  01020300        C0A80101        0003    0       0       3       FFFFFF00        0       0       0                                  
br-lan  03043836        C0A80101        0007    0       0       5       FFFFFFFF        0       0       0                                  
br-lan  C0A80100        00000000        0001    0       0       0       FFFFFF00        0       0       0
```

I want to extract only the line containing the Destination `01020300` and the Mask `FFFFFF00`

I tried with the following regexp but it does not works

```
cat /proc/net/route | grep "[^ \t\v]\+[ \t\v]\+$dest[ \t\v]\+[^ \t\v]\+[ \t\v]\+[^ \t\v]\+[ \t\v]\+[^ \t\v]\+[ \t\v]\+[^ \t\v]\+[ \t\v]\+[^ \t\v]\+[ \t\v]\+$mask"
```

I newbe wuth the regexp format. could you help me with a good regexp for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it is easier to work with `awk` for this:

```
$ awk '$2=="01020300" && $8=="FFFFFF00"' file
br-lan  01020300        C0A80101        0003    0       0       3       FFFFFF00        0       0       0
```

This way you can refer to the 2nd and 8th columns and check its value, without having to worry about the format.

In case your file separates fiels with tabs instead of spaces, use:

```
awk -F"\t" '$2=="01020300" && $8=="FFFFFF00"' file
```

And in case you want to give this values from bash variables, you can do (see comments, as Glenn Jackman, Etan Reisner and Ed Morton gave nice explanations):

```
awk -v d="$dest" -v m="$mask" '$2==d && $8==m' file
```

Comment: what could be the solution if my file separators could be spaces and tabs?

Comment: I tried `awk -F"\t" '$2=="$dest" && $8=="$mask"' file` but it does not work

Comment: For spaces and tabs you don't need to change `FS`/use the `-F` argument  that's the default.

Comment: You can't use shell variables in single quoted strings so `'$2=="$dest" && $8=="$mask"'` isn't doing what you expect. If you want to use the shell variables `$dest` and `$mask` you need to use `"$2==\"$dest\" && $8==\"$mask\""`.

Comment: @MOHAMED your `awk -F` example does not work because the `awk` command is in single quotes, which means that `$dest` and `$mask` won't be interpolated by the shell.

Comment: @EtanReisner, or use awk's `-v var=value` option: `awk -v d="$dest" -v m="$mask" '$2==d && $NF==m' file`

Comment: @EtanReisner If you were going to embed the value of shell variables in your awk script then the syntax would be `'$2=="'"$dest"'" && $8=="'"$mask"'"'` but you should never do that anyway.

Comment: @EdMorton An equally valid, and personally preferable, style but harder to be sure I typed correctly in this input box and harder to parse at a scan (also appears to clash with the "don't use single quotes" statement until you see what it is doing). But ultimately yeah, just don't do that.

Comment: @EtanReisner - FWIW what I showed is THE syntax to do it. The way you had it causes problems with shell positional parameter numbers being used in place of awk field numbers (think about what `$2` means in the 2 examples - in mine it's the contents of field 2 of the current input record, in yours it's the value of the 2nd positional parameter passed to your shell), having to escape other characters, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton Fair enough. I wasn't thinking about needing to escape the positional parameters in that example (though I do know you have to do that). I'm more than happy to let you pick the color of this bike shed since we agree that they any color worse than not painting it in the first place.

Comment: @MOHAMED see update, and most of all see very interesting comments above this. Thanks to all commenters!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works but I had to replace `$NF==m` with `$8==m` in your awk expression. may be you have to edit your question

Comment: Nicd to read that, @MOHAMED . I updated to indicate so. For future references, `$NF` would mean last field (and `$(NF-1)` the penultimate and so far...).